# Google assistant Push Notification result is 404

Tags: java, actions-on-google

I am tring to send a push notification to my google assistant, but there is an error.

> "code": 404, "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "status":
>   "NOT_FOUND"

At first, I refer to the `aog` doc about send notifications in java language, I think my `userId` and intent are correct, if wrong input the response is not 404.

So I try to build in [actionssdk-updates-java](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-updates-java), just follow the setup Instructions, my assistant can successfully build, and the conversation is work, when i try to "send notification", the response is still 404.

Does any one know how to solve this problem?

[image: Push Notification result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason recently.
The example code class Target need locale parameter,
because my project's locale is not english.
Once i create a project with english, push notification works fine.
In [Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications#java) docs, the difference between java and nodejs is locale in target.

Answer (score 0):

To send push notifications, you must first enable the Actions API for your project.

To enable the Actions API:

1. In the [Google Cloud Platform console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), select your *Project ID* from the dropdown
2. From **Menu ☰** > **APIs & Services** > **Library** > select **Actions API** > **Enable**